# Magento 1.9 vertical menu issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i've stumbled on a relatively known issue, but i cant find the solution.

I am using magento 1.9 CE

I have found some code to show a vertical menu of the current categorie with its children, and on the homepage the root category and everything works fine except 1 little detail. The subcategories don't load in the order of the backend. It's important that the same order as how it is setup in teh backend loads. I have tried allot of variations, like getCChildrenCategories but then it results in a blnak page. I also found menu's that do work, but then when i visit the homepage, i get an error and the page turns blank.

This is the code i am using at the moment.

```
<section class="block-layered-nav custom-left-menu" role="navigation">
<div class="block-content">
<?php 
echo "<dl id='narrow-by-list2'>";
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$subcatid = $_category->getId();
$parentCategory = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/navigation')->getCurrentCategory()->parent_id;
$name = $_category->getName();
               $root_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcatid);
               $subcategories = $root_category->getChildren();
               if($subcategories != "")
               {
                 echo "<span class='h3'>Categorie</span><ol>";
                 foreach(explode(',',$subcategories) as $subcategory) {
                 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcategory);
                 echo '<li><a href="'.$category->getURL() .'" title="'.$category->getName().'" />'.$category->getName().'</a></li>';
               }
               }
               else
               {
                   echo "<span class='h3'>Categorie</span><ol>";
                   $root_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategory);
                   $subcategories = $root_category->getChildren();
                   foreach(explode(',',$subcategories) as $subcategory) {
                           $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcategory);
                           echo '<li><a href="'.$category->getURL() .'" title="'.$category->getName().'" />'.$category->getName().'</a>';
               }             
            } 
echo "</ol>";
?>
</div>
</section>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. All i know is that, somewhere in this code its not calling the categories the right way, i also tried:

```
$currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
```

but this results in a blank homepage.

Here is a link to the dev enviremont: http://dev.smoldersbv.nl/schroeven-en-bouten.html

If you hover over the main navigation you see a different order, the correct order, then on the left menu.

Comment: this will help you; http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/how-to-sort-categories-as-they-are-shown-in-admin

Answer (score 0):

This is normal `$this->getCurrentCategory()` get the current category = the category you are currently browsing. 
On the home page you are not in a category, like on any other cms pages or even on the contact us page, ... (and there are lots more). So you have nothing in the *current category* which is obvious.

Comment: This is true, but this function also shows the root category on the homepage, which all works fine, but what i need it to do is get the right order as is in the backend i've added a link in the post aswell for ppl to see the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

The way of the requests where wrong therefor this menu is unable to produce the order of the backend so i ended up using a whole different mockup.

thnx for looking anyway.